# Drop down menu still visible in Internet explorer

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

This is very weird issue happening just with Internet Explorer. I made some works in a web with Wordpress, and my client asked me to remove some links in a Drop down menu in the Menu Bar. I made this change as he asked, but then i have found that just in a particular page of the Website in the menu bar this drop down menu is still visible in IE, why? The "funny" thing is that this is happening just in a menu bar of one page of the Website, and only with IE. Is it a normal issue? how it's possible to figure it out? .

This is the [web](http://www.creativesquaresummercamp.com/) and this is the [page](http://www.creativesquaresummercamp.com/safety-and-supervision/) where the dropdown menu is still visible in the *About link* in the menu bar.

The only extra plugins i have installed are: W3 Total Cache and JS & CSS Script Optimizer.

Comment: The `About` menu and all it's items are the same for me in IE & Chrome. 4 items. You cleared the w3 cache AND the browser cache right?

Comment: for me just in Internet explorer the items in about link are visibles in the page http://www.creativesquaresummercamp.com/safety-and-supervision/